# How to play selected video from video list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video, material-ui

I am working with react js. I have a video list and there are controller buttons which play and pause for every video. (Video list is the GridList which component of material-ui) and I want to that, if the user click on a video from the video list, the selected video should play. I try to do that with refs and play() method but everytime, the user whatever which select video just the last video play. I don't understand why it is like that.

```
<GridList cols={2} style={styles.gridList} cellheight="auto"
 onChange={this.changeNum}>

  {videoData.map((tile,i) => (
    <GridTile
       key={tile.video} title={tile.vidTitle} style={styles.gridTile}
       actionIcon={<div>
        <IconButton><PlayIcon color="white" onClick={this.playVideo.bind(this,"vidRef")} /></IconButton>
        <IconButton><PauseIcon color="white" onClick={this.pauseVideo.bind(this)} /></IconButton>
        </div>}
      >
        <video ref="vidRef" src={tile.video} type="video/mp4" controls></video>

    </GridTile>
  ))}
```

and the playVideo() method is:

```
playVideo(index) {
    this.refs.vidRef.play();
}
```

When the code like that it work as I told. I think "vidRef" value can be cause for the problem but I am not sure. Every click event play the last video because of the last video's ref value is "vidRef".

How can I do this right?

For example I clicked 3.mp4 but the last video (cut.mp4) played.

[image: design]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set unique name to ref for each video by adding index value to them, so for example it could be **ref={'vidRef' + i}'** to get **ref="vidRef1"**' for first video and '**ref="vidRef2"**' for second one and so on.

Then accessing to ref would be something like this **this.refs['vidRef' + i]**

Comment: Thanks it works. Actually, I try to set unique value  but I couldn't use this.refs like this.refs['vidRef'+i] :) Thanks again..